# How can I get Emacs to ignore certain keywords?

Tags: emacs, keyword, cedet, c-mode

I would like to tell emacs to treat some keywords (or regular expressions even better) as syntactic whitespace, or, in other words, to ignore them.
For example: emacs highlighting and cedet misinterpret the code

```
void function() some_compiler_specific_modifier(){
...
}
```

as `some_compiler_specific_modifier` being the function name.

I have a list of the modifiers so I would love it if emacs could just ignore them whenever it finds them.

EDIT: the most important part is to make the cedet parser ignore these keywords...

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you can modify `semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-map` to include the symbols you want to have disappear.  Since you have lots of macros, and some of those macros apparently take an argument, you are probably better off create some new header, such as:

goofy.h:

```
   #define some_compiler_specific_modifier(A)
   #define some_other_compiler_modifier(B)
   // ...
```

and then add that to `semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-file`.

After modifying those variables, you may need to then call `semantic-c-reset-preprocessor-symbol-map` to get the changes to take effect.

Alternately, use the `ede-cpp-root-project` type and specify the above info via the configuration in that project style.  (See the doc for more on that.)